# thin line on top of tab bar not removed in iOS 15

Tags: swift, uitabbar, ios15

Tried using below code in iOS 15, but the thin line on top of tabbar is not removed but below code works in iOS 13, iOS 14

```
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

appearance.shadowImage = nil

appearance.shadowColor = nil

appearance.backgroundEffect = nil

appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that on iOS 15 this is working to remove the shadow line

```
tabBar.standardAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```swift
tabBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = nil
tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance.shadowColor = nil
```

Example in viewDidLoad :

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance?.shadowColor = nil
}
```

Comment: thanks @lluSioN, it works in iOS 15

Comment: thin line on top of tab bar appears back in iOS 15 on change in device orientation, please help

Comment: have written above code in viewDidLoad method, @lluSioN, please help for above comments

Comment: @user2552751 Look at my example in viewDidLoad, I have no problem when the orientation changes

Comment: @lluSioN, not sure it doesnt work for me on orientation change in iOS 15

Comment: @user2552751 Please add more code in your post, so we can find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this on tab bar class

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {

        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance

    }
    
}
```